# Summary of Callicles and Thrasymachus's arguments regarding injustice

Tags: ethics, plato, aristotle, socrates

I find somewhat odd to find out that there does not seem to exist concise summary or review of Callicles and Thrasymachus's arguments for supporting injustice, so I ask this question: what would be concise summary of Callicles and Thrasymachus's arguments regarding injustice, and what would be the summary of Socrates/Plato/Aristotle (if applicable)'s arguments against Callicles's and Thrasymachus's?

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy.SE! So, this seems a little problematic to me; is there any chance I can persuade you to [revise this a bit](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/posts/3312/edit) to focus a bit more closely on some specific challenge or problem you're encountering in your study of the work in question or the ideas in it?

Comment: Which brings up another point: you don't even mention the text you're reading! Please consider telling us a little more about the context and motivations behind your study of the *Republic* -- this is really important to help potential answerers frame responses. These are things like: what ideas, thinkers, texts you might be working through; what specific problem you're encountering and what sort of explanation you might be expecting; what you might have found out already; etc.

Answer (score 2):

Is there something that renders the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy [article](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/callicles-thrasymachus/) on the subject insufficient for your purposes?

I don't think you can reasonably expect a summary to be more concise than an encyclopedia article, and still be relatively useful.